# how to vlookup in excel if your table array with mixed data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to vlookup the values in `Column C` from `Column A` , the problem is the data I want to look for is mixed with text:

**Screen Shot:**

[image: Sample Table layout]

Comment: I can't see your screenshot. Which data is mixed? If lookup value is "x" and you expect to match that with "xyz" in table then you can use wild cards in VLOOKUP

Comment: in colomn A1 "SPAN PUR POS-55453717 000 INMA 432328xxxxxx7224R: 443083" in colomn C1 "443083" how to lookup "443083" in "SPAN PUR POS-55453717 000 INMA 432328xxxxxx7224R: 443083" ?

Answer (score 0):

Add another column with a formula that extracts the values you are looking for, e.g. `=MID(A2;29;6)`, then do a vlookup with that column.

Comment: Depending on your regional settings, you may have to change the semicolons to commas in the formula. Or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your lookup values are 6 rightmost characters in `A:A` column, you need to create a helper column with something like:

```
=RIGHT(A1,6)
```

And then do `VLOOKUP` by those values.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you can avoid using any helper columns by using wildcards in the formula. If you simply trying to get the data from column A then try this formula:

`=VLOOKUP("*"&C1&"*",A:A,1,0)`